# CSV file import CMS Made Simple

Tags: file, csv, import, content-management-system

Can anybody tell me whats the format of CSV file which we can import to CMS Made Simple's Product Import function.

If a sample could be provided, that would be more helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you download the module, look in the root folder.
You'll find a "test_import.csv" file which guides you in detail about all kind of fields you can import !

However this is the basic syntax:
`#FLAG|#name|#sku|#details|#price|#create_date|#modified_date|#taxable|#status|#weight|#HIER|#CAT:new|#CAT:surplus|#FIELD:image:Image|#FIELD:textarea:Notes|#ATTRIBS`